# setLayoutManager NullPointException with RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to populate a `RecyclerView` with movie posters, however the app keeps crashing. Giving me this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference

I have looked at all the similar threads and tried everyones suggestions but it still wont work.

Here is my code where the error is:

```
//I get the error on this line
MoviesRV.setAdapter(movieAdapter);

//I set the layout which some people said may cause the error.
MoviesRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

Here's my MovieAdapter class

```
package com.example.myapplication1
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context ;
    List<Movie> mData;

    public MovieAdapter(Context context, List<Movie> mData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mData = mData;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.content_movie,viewGroup,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
        myViewHolder.TvTitle.setText(mData.get(i).getTitle());
        myViewHolder.ImgMovie.setImageResource(mData.get(i).getThumbnail());
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView TvTitle;
        private ImageView ImgMovie;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            TvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_id);
            ImgMovie = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_poster);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
package com.example.myapplication1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Menu;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private RecyclerView MoviesRV;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MoviesRV = findViewById(R.id.RV_Posters);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_watching, R.id.nav_settings,
                R.id.nav_contact, R.id.nav_share)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);


        List<Movie> movies1 = new ArrayList<>();
        movies1.add(new Movie("Yu-Gi-Oh! The Movie", R.drawable.yugiohthemovie));

        MovieAdapter movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(this, movies1);
        MoviesRV.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
        MoviesRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

**Here is my logcat and HomeFragment**

```
2019-08-22 20:34:43.899 10976-10976/com.example.webtoons E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.webtoons, PID: 10976
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.webtoons/com.example.webtoons.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.webtoons.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

**HomeFragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RV_Posters"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="489dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.228"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Firstly, please don't just link to your code off-site. You need to provide a [mcve] in the question itself. Secondly, the error is not occurring because of the `Adapter`. The `RecyclerView` is null. If the snippet you've posted is indeed where the Exception is being thrown, then `MoviesRV` is null.

Comment: Sorry, i added the class to the site. MoviesRV is my RecyclerView, it cant be left null?

Comment: Again, the issue is not with the `Adapter`. `MoviesRV` is null. And no, it cannot be null, if you want to call methods on it. I'm not sure why you might think that.

Comment: For us to be able to determine why `MoviesRV` is null, you'll need to post `MainActivity`'s code and layout XML.

Comment: I added the MainActivity class and the HomeFragment layout where the RecyclerView is. This is a Navigation Drawer Activity

Comment: If the `RecyclerView` is in a `Fragment`, you should be handling it in the `Fragment`, not the `Activity`. You need to move that code to `HomeFragment`.

Comment: What's the name of the layout you added? is it activity_main?

Comment: Thats probably it! I will add the code to the HomeFragment Class, thank you